# How to get Oozie's dependency check to list the dataset full path name instead of coord:latest(0)?

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator, oozie-workflow

With an Oozie coordinator and workflow, I see the following in the Coord Job Log for a specific action:

```
JOB[0134742-190911204352052-oozie-oozi-C] ACTION[0134742-190911204352052-oozie-oozi-C@1] [0134742-190911204352052-oozie-oozi-C@1]::CoordActionInputCheck:: Missing deps: ${coord:latest(0)}#${coord:latest(0)}#${coord:latest(0)}#${coord:latest(0)}#${coord:latest(0)}#${coord:latest(0)}
```

It seems the full path names are missing. If the path name is not specified in the coordinator with latest(0), the paths are available as seen here:

```
JOB[0134742-190911204352052-oozie-oozi-C] ACTION[0134742-190911204352052-oozie-oozi-C@1] [0134742-190911204352052-oozie-oozi-C@1]::CoordActionInputCheck:: Missing deps:hdfs://labs-xxx/data/funcxx/inputs/uploads/reports-for-targeting/20190923/14
```

Later the paths is resolved as:

```
JOB[0134742-190911204352052-oozie-oozi-C] ACTION[0134742-190911204352052-oozie-oozi-C@1] [0134742-190911204352052-oozie-oozi-C@1]::ActionInputCheck:: File:hdfs://labs-xxx/data/funcxx/inputs/uploads/reports-for-targeting/20190923/14, Exists? :true
```

How can I see the *full path* name instead of the ${coord:latest(0)} strings?

Answer (score -1):

You can check this vis oozie cli - 
`oozie job -info 0134742-190911204352052-oozie-oozi-C@1`

Comment: This only prints the first unmet dependency and just as @codeaperature mentioned on the question, it displays this: `!!${coord:future(0, 1024)}` instead of the path.